# IBDesignable error for Test Target

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ibdesignable

I am trying to use a custom UITextField in my storyboard. However, everytime I set the Custom class of a UITextField as my CustomTextField, I get an error

```
IB Designables: 
Failed to update auto layout status: dlopen(MyAppTests.xctest, 
1): Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
Referenced from: MyAppTests.xctest
Reason: image not found
```

As soon as I revert the textfield's custom class to a regular UITextField, the error disappears. I have added the CustomTextField's swift file to the Test target but still no solution. I have also applied the solution shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030951/ibdesignable-errors-when-adding-to-tests-target) with no success.

Anyone have ideas? (I would like to keep my test target so deleting it is not an option)

Thanks in advance.