# How do I use classes from my module in XCTestCase?

Tags: xcode, swift, tdd

I am trying to test this class (`Swiftris/Swifteris/Array2D.swift`):

```
class Array2D<T> {

    let rows: Int
    let columns: Int

    var array: Array<T?>

    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns

        array = Array<T?>(count:rows * columns, repeatedValue: nil)
    }

    subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
        get {
            return array[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set {
            array[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

With this simple test (`Swiftris/SwiftrisTests/Array2DTest.swift`):

```
import UIKit
import XCTest

class Array2DTest: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    func testHasRows() {
        var array: Array2D = Array2D(rows: 10, columns: 15)
        XCTAssertEqual(array.rows, 20, "an Array2D instance should have the correct number of rows")
    }
}
```

It unexplainably fails to resolve Array2D:

```
Swifteris/SwifterisTests/Array2DTest.swift:12:20: Use of undeclared type 'Array2D'
```

Do I need to import my own module into my tests? This is pretty puzzling since I did the exact same thin in another project and had no trouble resolving classes under test.

Comment: I´m running the tests though Xcode - in case this matters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 2 options.

#### Add `Array2D.swift` to `SwifterisTests` Target Membership

It's very simple

[image: screenshot]

#### Import `Swifteris` to `Array2DTest.swift`

Basically this method is recommended, but it's relatively annoying.

At first, you have to declare **all** testable classes/methods/properties as `public`:

Array2D.swift:

```
public class Array2D<T> {

    public let rows: Int
    public let columns: Int

    private var array: Array<T?>

    public init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns

        array = Array<T?>(count:rows * columns, repeatedValue: nil)
    }

    public subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
        get {
            return array[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set {
            array[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Then, import main module `Swifteris` to test module `SwifterisTests`

```
import XCTest
import Swifteris

// Here Array2D is avaiable.
```

More discussion on this Q/A: [Swift, access modifiers and unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994593/swift-access-modifiers-and-unit-testing)

Comment: Any idea why doing `Array2D(rows: 9, columns: 10)` gives me `Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`?

Comment: Because you didn't provide any information about `T`. For example , `var array = Array2D<String>(rows: 9, columns: 10)` would be OK, in that case `T` will be bound to `String`.