# Swift Singleton Init Called Twice in XCTest

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, singleton

With Swift, a singleton initializer is called **twice** when running XCTest unit tests.

No problems with Objective-C, though, the init() method is only called once, as expected.

Here's how to build the two test projects:

## Objective-C

### Singleton Class

Create an empty Objective-C Project with tests. Add following bare-bones singleton:

```
#import "Singleton.h"

@implementation Singleton

+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance
{
    static Singleton *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[Singleton alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"%@", self);
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

### AppDelegate

In the application delegate add a call to the singleton like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [Singleton sharedInstance];
    return YES;
}
```

### XCTestCase

Also add a call to the singleton to the generated test class:

```
- (void)testExample {
    [Singleton sharedInstance];
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    XCTAssert(YES, @"Pass");
}
```

### Results

If you add a breakpoint to the singleton's `init` method and run the tests, the **breakpoint will only be hit once**, as expected.

## Swift

Now do the create a new Swift project and do the same thing.

### Singleton

Create a singleton, add the test target to its `Target Memberships`

```
class Singleton {
    class var sharedInstance : Singleton {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance : Singleton? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = Singleton()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    init() {
        NSLog("\(self)")
    }
}
```

### AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Singleton.sharedInstance
    return true
}
```

### XCTestCase

```
func testExample() {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    Singleton.sharedInstance
    XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
}
```

### Results

This time, if you add a breakpoint to the singleton's `init` method and run the tests, the **breakpoint will be hit twice,** first from the app delegate, then from the test case, i.e. you'll have two instances of the singleton.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: It's not concerned about the question, but you might want to see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since application module and tests module are separated modules, when you add the `Singleton.swift` file to test target member, `YourApp.Singleton` and `YourAppTest.Singleton` are not same class. That's why `init` called twice.

Instead of that, you should `import` your main module in your test file:

```
import YourAppName

func testExample() {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    Singleton.sharedInstance
    XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
}
```

and your `Singleton` class must be declared as `public`. see [Swift, access modifiers and unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994593/swift-access-modifiers-and-unit-testing)

```
public class Singleton {
    public class var sharedInstance : Singleton {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance : Singleton? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = Singleton()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    init() {
        NSLog("\(self)")
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove `Singleton.swift` from test target membership.

Comment: Wow wish I'd seen this 2 hours ago

Comment: YES! My issue was that I had my singleton added to both targets, thus it was able to create separate singleton instances ... thanks!

Comment: I have all of the following setup correctly, and the issue remains. Weird thing is that my project builds fine, but the failure only happens when I try to render the view on my project's first SwiftUI file. Very weird. Build failure is on my import of my appname in the test, and build error references this post.